# Vue CLI - How to have components on multiple pages (Flask)

Tags: python, flask, vue.js, vue-cli

I have a NON spa application with pages served by python flask. I am trying to move to using vuecli so that i can get the benefits of ES6. What i thought i would need to do is in the master.jinja2 template i would just wrap the entire thing in . Then i would create components and on the pages where i need those components i could just do .

What's happening instead is the entire app disappears on page render.

How i can i prevent the global Vue instance created by cli in master.js from replacing all content and only load the components when they are on the page.

Thanks not new to vue but i have done everything with include js files is es5 prior to this so its a bit different i think i am just missing something basic to get this to work.

If there is a better way to get what i am after please let me know. If this is in the wrong place please point me to the correct place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to comment out the render line in master.js and then register the components on the main vue instance.